# Taxonomy terms are not listed in the order of their weight

Tags: nodes, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a multilingual site and each language has its own taxonomy terms. In `node/add` form terms of the current language are displayed.

I ordered tags in alphabetical order and also set weight for each one to make sure each one is in a right position. Terms are in right order in `admin/structure/taxonomy/tags` But in  `node/add` form terms are displayed in a random order and on each page refresh a new order is displayed. How can I order the terms?

Comment: Can't test now but I believe form creation function simply does not use term weight and you would need to recreate options in hook form alter. How to do it is another matter, posing this hint because 6h without answer seems long for so  fundamental issue.

Comment: @Mołot I tried to alter the `$form` variable in `hook_form_alter` but found nothing about individual terms and their order !

Comment: Of course - options are rendered in the order they were added, so the only way I know is to remove them and then add again, this time basing on weights. Thus - nothing weight-specific in documentation.

Comment: @Mołot there is no way to do this at all, my website is a virtual network like `Instagram.com`, There are about 20,000 contents (of high resolution images) so I can't remove the tags. If I do this, I will lose the tags attached to the  contents.

Comment: Remove #options in hook form alter, not tags from a site.

Comment: @Mołot sorry for misunderstanding, Ok, I try now